# Make a magic tag work with Custom Post Types

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, facebook

I have a custom post type:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_foto' );

function register_cpt_foto() {

    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( 'Fotoalbums', 'foto' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Fotoalbum', 'foto' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Nieuw fotoalbum', 'foto' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Voeg nieuw fotoalbum toe', 'foto' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Bewerk fotoalbum', 'foto' ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'Nieuw fotoalbum', 'foto' ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'Bekijk fotoalbum', 'foto' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Zoek in fotoalbums', 'foto' ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'Geen fotoalbums gevonden', 'foto' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'Geen fotoalbums gevonden in de prullenmand', 'foto' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent foto:', 'foto' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Foto\'s', 'foto' ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'description' => 'Het posttype dat alle fotoalbums verzorgt.',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'page-attributes' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,


        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'fotos',
            'with_front' => false
        ),
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( 'foto', $args );
}
```

Now, I am using a plugin called [Facebook Photo Fetcher](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-photo-fetcher/). You can *fetch* FB albums with a *magic tag*. You only have to post this as HTML:

```
<!--FBGallery 1234567890123456789 cols=4 max=16 swapHead=1 --><!--/FBGallery-->
```

When you save this post, it is converted to a complete post with all the images inserted etc. The problem is: the plugin doesn't seem to recognise this tag! Or maybe it is disabled for custom post types? I don't know, but it does absolutely nothing and I don't know why!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Comment reposted as answer at request of OP author:]

Rather than deleting them, why don't you add your post_type to the if() statement:

```
//Don't process anything but POSTS and PAGES (i.e. no revisions)
if( $data['post_type'] != 'post' && $data['post_type'] != 'page' && $data['post_type'] != 'foto' )
    return $data;
```

As that comment in the code makes quite clear, without that statement, you'll be processing all the revisions as well which probably isn't what you want (considering that the plugin author disabled it).

(Also, "hacking" a plugin like this will only work until you need to update the plugin. Make sure to contact the plugin author and talk to them about supporting custom post types.)

Answer (score 1):

Found it:
In `facebook-photo-fetcher/_output_gallery.php` delete lines 15 to 17. These ones:

```
//Don't process anything but POSTS and PAGES (i.e. no revisions)
if( $data['post_type'] != 'post' && $data['post_type'] != 'page')
    return $data;
```

And it should work!

Comment: Rather than deleting them, why don't you add yours post_type to the `if()` statement. As that comment makes quite clear, now you'll be processing all the revisions as well which probably isn't what you want (considering that the plugin author disabled it). Also, "hacking" a plugin like this will only work until you need to update the plugin. Make sure to contact the plugin author and talk to them about supporting custom post types.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed very much easier and neater! If you post your comment as an answer, I'll mark that one as correct!

Comment: Glad I could help. Answer posted below.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for any already registered custom post type

```
function tags_for_foto() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'foto');
}
add_action('init', 'tags_for_foto');
```